# Display results in SQL that meet the criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, having-clause

select only those top 10 hospitals that have both kinds of ICU and SICU beds, i.e. only hospitals that have at least 1 ICU bed and at least 1 SICU bed can be included in this part of the analysis. Here is what I have so far

```
select bu.business_name as 'Hospital Name'
,sum(be.license_beds) as Total_Licenses
,case when be.bed_id = 4 then 'ICU' end as "ICU"
,case when be.bed_id = 15 then 'SICU' end as "SICU"
from bed_fact be 
join bed_type bt 
  on be.bed_id = bt.bed_id
join business bu 
  on be.ims_org_id = bu.ims_org_id
where be.bed_id = 4 
    or be.bed_id = 15
and be.license_beds IS NOT NULL
group 
    by bu.business_name
order 
    by Total_Licenses DESC
limit 10
;
```

I need to some how only count the hospital that has at least one of ICU or SICU value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select 
    bu.business_name as Hospital_Name,
    sum(be.license_beds) as Total_Licenses,
    sum(be.bed_id = 4) as ICU,
    sum(be.bed_id = 15) as SICU
from bed_fact be 
inner join bed_type bt on be.bed_id = bt.bed_id
inner join business bu on be.ims_org_id = bu.ims_org_id
where be.bed_id in (4, 15) and be.license_beds is not null
group by bu.business_name
having ICU > 0 and SICU > 0
order by Total_Licenses desc
limit 10
```

If you don't what the counts in the resultset, then move the aggregate functions to the `having` clause:

```
select 
    bu.business_name as Hospital_Name,
    sum(be.license_beds) as Total_Licenses
from bed_fact be 
inner join bed_type bt on be.bed_id = bt.bed_id
inner join business bu on be.ims_org_id = bu.ims_org_id
where be.bed_id in (4, 15) and be.license_beds is not null
group by bu.business_name
having sum(be.bed_id = 4) > 0 and sum(be.bed_id = 15) > 0
order by Total_Licenses desc
limit 10
```

Comment: great, one more question i need to display only the hospital name and the total_license but wih the conditions that you added. How can I do that?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.